# how to restore the repo after git fetch?

Tags: git

After changing origin remote URL (it was moved) and doing a `git update`, I found myself having a repo that has every commit & branch double (up to the point of my last fetch before). However, gitk shows one common initial ancestor (the 'start' of the repo).

The file FETCH_HEAD contains 24 entries. Is there any git command that restores my repo as it was before the fetch?

Small detail info: my local repo feeds exclusively from a single remote, and own branches are pushed to another remote.

Comment: git doesn't have a command named update ...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like when the repo was moved all of the history was lost or modified (different sha-1 hashes meaning git doesn't know about common ancestry), as I assume you meant git pull not a git update.

If you have nothing to lose in terms of any of the files and or you haven't made any changes (best to do this in a branch first and see if it does what you want it to do) you can try the following:

```
git checkout -b tmaster
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Now check to see if everything is correct, if it is the case, delete the `master` branch and rename `tmaster` to `master`.

Any branches you have made though will still have the old history associated with it, you will have to create new branches, and `cherry-pick` one by one the commits you've made that are changes on top of origin's master.

---

First I would also run

```
git remote update --prune
git fetch --all
```

Comment: I ran the remote update --prune, and it deletad a couple of branches, but the main problem is still persisting. BTW: I did this all on a local copy of my local repo, eliminating risks. Perhaps I should start a new with a clone of my own remote repo, and than add the updates from the mainline repo. Drawback of this method: no knowledgd of what went wrong, resp. about "how to" restore after fetch (it really was fetch, because I like to inspect the fetch result with gitk prior to merging it).

Comment: Would you be able to post the output of a git log somewhere? If all you did was fetch you should be able to simply remove those branches to revert back to the previous state.

Comment: I already tried removing branches, but I have to experiment more thoroughly - if one overlooked (did the branches listed in FETCH_HEAD), this may keep a lot unchanged... BTW: the SHA's are indeed different. (note: next hours out of office...)

Comment: What I would look for first is why the sha's changed when the repo was moved (they shouldn't have changed at all). If you can my suggestion would be to clone from the new origin and go from there. That is most likely the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

(long time due in priority project) - new info: it was told that history of new repo URL has been rewritten intentioally. I'd open a new topic with more appropriate title.